# Dynamically change DefaultLeafIcons in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid

Overview:

I have an advancedDataGrid that I am using a GroupingCollection on and I want to be able to change the individual DefaultLeafIcons (no children icon) based upon a value I get from the dataProvider. Can anyone shed some light on how this is done.

Details:
In the data that I receive there is an isShared value that is either 1 or 0 if the value is 1 I want to be able to display abc.png if the value is 0 display xyz.png.

I am using Flex 3.6 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should implement an ***iconFunction*** for the datagrid.

a sample iconFunction implementation would look like the following.

```
[Embed("abc.png")]
private var abcIcon:Class;

[Embed("xyz.png")]
private var xyzIcon:Class;

private function iconFunc(item:Object):Class {
   var iconClass:Class;
   var itemType:int = item.isShared; //TypeCast item accordingly.
   switch(itemType)
   { case 1: iconClass = abcIcon;
             break;
     case 0: iconClass = xyzIcon;
         break;
    }
    return iconClass;                       
 }
```

Remember to link the *iconFunc* with the datagrid by adding the following attribute.

```
iconFunction="iconFunc"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This really should be better documented.